# Which is the best Active Directory explorer for making custom queries?

Tags: active-directory

I am accessing Active Directory and need to execute custom queries.

I am currently using JXplorer and AD explorer, but but explorers have issues and I cannot get my work done.

Do you have any recommendations of which is the best Active Directory explorer?

Comment: "Best" is relative. What will you be using it for? (managing accounts, troubleshooting, etc.) What do you not like about the tools you've tried?

Comment: I want to make custom queries and these tools don't provide that

Answer (score 3):

Active Directory Users and Computers (Microsoft's own AD browser) can do custom searches.

If you're running Windows 10, just install this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

For Windows 7, it's a two-step process. Instructions are here: https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/windows-7/windows-7-how-to-install-the-active-directory-users-and-computers-tools/

Once installed, here's how you can do a custom LDAP search:

1. Right-click the domain, click 'Find..'
2. In the 'Find' drop-down box, select 'Custom Search'
3. Click the 'Advanced' tab.

Then you can type your own LDAP query there. Something to be aware of: If there is a syntax error with your query, it won't tell you. It'll just show no results.

Comment: Your Windows 7 link is dead.

Comment: @joeb Thanks. Looks like they changed the format of their site, but the content is still there. I updated the link.